# Is it possible to change the incoming, but not outgoing SSH port in OS X Yosemite?

Tags: ssh, osx-yosemite

I SSH into my workstation, which is a mac running OS X Yosemite, daily. Unfortunately, I noticed a while back that enabling remote login into my machine has put it under the fire of many automated dictionary attacks trying to log in using the default port, 22.

To make my machine more secure, I changed the SSH port. To do so, I edited the `/etc/services` file, and changed the following two lines:

```
ssh              2123/udp     # SSH Remote Login Protocol                                                                
ssh              2123/tcp     # SSH Remote Login Protocol
```

That greatly reduced the number of dictionary attacks, but now when I try to SSH from my workstation to other machines, I always need to specify the port (which is usually port 22).

This is easy enough for most simple tasks, just specify the port when SSHing in:

```
ssh -p22 me@another.computer.com
```

It becomes a pain for more complicated tasks where specifying the port is not an option, but it can still be done by adding an entry in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com                                                                 
   Hostname ssh.github.com                                                      
   Port 443
```

Between these two options, I could always connect to any machine I wanted to connect to. However, I'm now writing a script that will connect to machines that will have different IP addresses (and domain names), and there is no optional argument to specify the port number.

I have also been getting frustrated that it does not default to port 22 for outgoing connections, but I do not want to change my incoming port back to 22.

Is it possible to change the incoming SSH port, but still have the default outgoing SSH port? That is, can I only allow people to login to my workstation using port 2123, but when I try connecting to other machines, the default port it tries to use is port 22?

I'm running OS X 10.10.2 Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `ssh` port back in `/etc/services' - that sets the *defined* port for the ssh protocol.

Then change the port that `sshd` listens on. On OS-X this is more complicated than it need be. See https://serverfault.com/questions/18761/how-to-change-sshd-port-on-mac-os-x